# Ubuntu 14.04: Folding at Home crashed with SIGSEV in strlen()

Tags: 14.04, crash, installed-programs

How this can be fixed? 
New installation did not helped.

```
Folding@home (FAH or F@h) is a distributed computing application.
```

It crashes during startup.

1. I have no GPU.
2. FAH 7.4.4.

Comment: I am sorry, but I'm unable to understand your problem (What does "folding at home" mean?). Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what you want to do that does not work. Thank you.

Comment: @ByteCommander, question body edited.

Comment: Okay, but I still don't know what you did before it crashed. Please be more detailed and include as much information related to this problem as possible.

Comment: @ByteCommander, Numix theme and icons were installed. Tried to set default, did not helped.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)**  Did it ever work?  Do you have a GPU? What version of F@H???  As our question is stated, **it's unclear**, so please [edit] your question and add more details (logs would be a start)

Comment: @Fabby, thank you VERY MUCH! I attached answers, except logs. Where I can find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folding@Home is extremely vector-intensive and you need a GPU to do anything reasonable nowadays...  Look for another @Home project to give your CPU cycles to (something that doesn't need a GPU)...

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...*

If you insist on using F@H, set the `gpu-usage` setting to 0.  If you don't know how to do that, head over to the [Folding@Home Support forum](http://foldingforum.org/) because this is now *really* getting off-topic on Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I completely agree, but CPU is supported by FAH, so I need a way to fix this.

Comment: @ArthurKharkivskiy: answer edited and voted to close question.